What are these commands in the code?
I see the code:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{\textsf}}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lotomat_input_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_lotomat_input_tl { ; } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_lotomat_input_seq { , } \l_lotomat_input_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_lotomat_input_seq #2
 }
\tl_new:N \l_lotomat_input_tl
\seq_new:N \l_lotomat_input_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

What do functions mean?(\seq_new:N, \tl_replace_all:Nnn etc.)

these are all documented in texdoc interface3

Welcome to tex.sx.

see the code where?

These are the L3 programming layer commands (also known as expl3)

\tl_new:N \l_lotomat_input_tl

declares a new token list variable

\seq_new:N \l_lotomat_input_seq

declares a sequence variable

\tl_set:Nn \l_lotomat_input_tl { #1 }

save the argument #1 in the variable \l_lotomat_input_tl

  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_lotomat_input_tl { ; } { , }

redefine \l_lotomat_input_tl replacing every ; by ,

  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_lotomat_input_seq { , } \l_lotomat_input_tl

make a sequence by splitting up the saved token list on each comma

  \seq_map_function:NN \l_lotomat_input_seq #2

apply the command passed in argument #2 in turn to each item of the sequence just made

So you get

from
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{\textsf}}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lotomat_input_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_lotomat_input_tl { ; } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_lotomat_input_seq { , } \l_lotomat_input_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_lotomat_input_seq #2
 }
\tl_new:N \l_lotomat_input_tl
\seq_new:N \l_lotomat_input_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{aaa,bbb;ccc;ddd}[\fbox]

\end{document}

as first the ; are changed to , then the squence is made by splitting on , and then finally \fbox is applied to each item in the sequence so applied separately to aaa, bbb, ccc, and ddd.

Thank you very much!
Is this only in expl3?
Where can I read the documentation about this in more detail?

expl3 is part of the format so you need no package to use these comamnds see texdoc expl3 texdoc interface3 for more details @Анатолий

Thank you very much for solving my problem
